# Add title to meanmenu with css :after

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

I've seen a couple of posts about how to set a title to the MeanMenu jQuery Responsive menu plugin but they do it by editing the js. I was wondering if it's possible to do it through css using :after? I've tried but failed dismally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add text using CSS :after. See Snippet. This is about all of the help I can provide without seeing the actual code you are using. Keep in mind when using :after that the pseudo-element that gets inserted into the html is contained within the element that has the :before or :after applied to it. So, the `nav:after` pseudo element will be contained in the `nav` element "after" the rest of the child elements.

```css
nav:after{
  display:block;
  content:"This is text inserted using :after";
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<nav><!-- Empty element that gets content added by using :after --></nav>
```

**EDIT: Added screen shot.** It may not be working for you due to the specificity of your selector or the location in which you are declaring the styles in your css file. You can try greater specificity by using something like this:

```
.mean-bar > nav.mean-nav:after {
  display:block;
  content:"This is text inserted using :after";
  clear:both;
  color:white;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried something very similar and it doesn't get placed in the right place. You can see my website at mylingerie-buntingford.co.uk. The meanmenu appears for smaller screens (obviously). Suggestions very welcome!

Comment: I tested on your site and it appears to work as expected (See Screenshot in Answer). What exactly have you tried? Where exactly do you want your inserted text to appear?

Comment: I'd tried on the <a> and first <span> tags without it working. Yours does indeed work, thanks. I actually want the text to the right of the hamburger icon. Taking your solution, I've positioned the text absolutely (relative to the containing div) which gives me exactly what I want. Many thanks @IMI.

Comment: @PedroKTFC - I'm glad that you got it working. If you feel that this answer provided the solution to your problem then please consider marking it as accepted.